# iOS - Where to save sensitive data - NSUserDefaults, Keychain, something else?

Tags: iphone, ios, nsuserdefaults, keychain

I am developing an app that, while it doesn't have "credentials" per se, it does assign some identifying information to each user for use with a remote service. This info should be as invisible as possible for security. Not even the user should be able to access this info.

I haven't found a definitive response to where to save this info for the user in the app.

1) Given the sensitivity of the data, keychain would seem like the proper place, but this data is not exactly usernames and passwords. Does that make a difference?

2)From what I can tell NSUserDefaults, as long as you don't expose it through a settings view, seems private as well but I assume not as secure as Keychain itself.

Opinions?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: everyone can read the plist that `NSUserDefaults` saved to without jailbreak the device.

Comment: Read this: http://blog.hawkimedia.com/2012/04/lockbox-easily-secure-your-apps-sensitive-data/

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is old but I stumbled upon it so here is what I have found. NSUserDefaults stores data unencrypted so it should not be used for sensitive data. Users with a little knowledge can access it from a computer. Keychain would be the appropriate place if it needs to be completely hidden. If you are storing personal information that doesn't need to be kept secret then NSUserDefaults is fine.

This is a great article that explains it further:

https://www.andyibanez.com/nsuserdefaults-not-for-sensitive-data/